# Listen to js variable change

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope, window

Let's say there is a code in **place 2**

```
var place2IsReady = true;
```

In **place 1** I need to implement the logic below :

```
Once place2IsReady value was changed (to true) then display alert('ready!');
```

Notes:

- *place2IsReady* variable is not available in the scope of **place 1**.
- the code from **place 1** gets executed before **place 2** gets executed (or there is a race condition).

**Solution 1**

I believe I can use window.place2IsReady instead and use setTimeout/setInterval in place 1 until I get `window.place2IsReady === true`.

Any better options? Using Listeners? On the variable change?

P.S. I need to track **only first possible change** of *place2IsReady*.

Is there a better way? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using some framework?

Comment: Variables don't do any sort of notification on change. You either have to continually poll and check if the variable changed or actually use some pattern or library that will let you track changes.

Comment: @distante My preferable answer: No.  JS + TS + jQuery in some places. Vanilla JS solution is preferable.

Comment: "place2IsReady" can be an object instead of a Boolean value?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are looking for, but you may use https://javascript.info/property-accessors getter/setter to do dependent operation on execution of setter's call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a listener for the variable change using `setTimeout`, something like:

```js
let place2IsReady = false;

setReadyListener();

// testing wait 2 seconds to set place2IsReady to true
// so: an alert should occur after 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => place2IsReady = true, 2000);

function setReadyListener() {
  const readyListener = () => {
    if (place2IsReady) {
      return alert("Ready!");
    }
    return setTimeout(readyListener, 250);
  };
  readyListener();
}
```

A more generic listener 'factory' could be:

```js
let place2IsReady = false;
let fromObj = {
  place2IsReady: "busy",
  done() { this.place2IsReady = "done"; },
};
const listen = changeListenerFactory();

listen(
  () => place2IsReady, 
  () => console.log("place2IsReady") );
listen(
  () => fromObj.place2IsReady === "done", 
  () => console.log("formObj.place2IsReady done!") );
  
console.log("Listening...");

// test change variables with listeners
setTimeout(() => place2IsReady = true, 1000);
setTimeout(() => fromObj.done(), 3000);

function changeListenerFactory() {
  const readyListener = (condition, callback, delay) => {
    if (!condition || typeof condition !== "function") { return true; }
    if (condition()) {
      return callback();
    }
    setTimeout(() => readyListener(condition, callback, delay), delay);
  };
  
  return (condition, callback = () => {}, delay = 250) => 
    readyListener(condition, callback, delay);
}
```

Or maybe using a [Proxy](https://javascript.info/proxy) (with a *set trap*) works for you

```js
const readyState = new Proxy({ ready: false }, { 
  set (target, prop, val) {
    console.log(`readyState.ready changed from ${target[prop]} to ${val}`);
    target[prop] = val;
  }
});

console.log("Waiting for changes ...");
setTimeout(() => readyState.ready = true, 2000);
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain why place2IsReady = true; place2IsReady = false; place2IsReady = true; doesn't display the second alert?

Comment: I could, if I understood what you meant

Comment: @Kooilnc, got it, thank you, it was executed only once.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can replace place2IsReady with an object:

```
place2IsReady = {
  state: false,
  set ready(value) {
      this.state = value
      state && place_1_call()
  },
  get ready() { 
    return state
  }
}

place_1_call = () => {
  alert('ready')
}

place2IsReady.ready = true
```